# reactive props in Vue3 Treelist causes recursive updates

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, treeview, nodes, pinia

I am curently using [vue3-tree](https://vue3-tree.netlify.app/guide/#installation) for my project and im trying to configure the nodes, im using pinia to store props.filter.data up to the parent, but i keep getting this error:

***Uncaught (in promise) Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.***

My component currently looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <div data-cy="filter-tree-list">
    <tree
      data-cy="filter-tree-list-component"
      data-test="filter-tree-list"
      class="flex flex-row w-full justify-start items-stretch rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300"
      v-if="props.filter.data"
      rowHoverBackground="#b2ffff40"
      :nodes="props.filter.data"
      :use-checkbox="true"
      @update:nodes="onUpdate"
      @nodeClick="onNodeClick"
    >
    </tree>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { inject, defineEmits, defineProps, ref, watch } from "vue";
    import { Filter } from "../../types/common/filter";
    
    interface Node {
      id: string;
      label: string;
      nodes: Array<Node>;
      checked?: boolean;
    }
    
    const piniaRef: unknown = inject("piniaStore");
    
    const props = defineProps({
      filter: {
        type: Object as () => Filter,
        required: true,
      },
      isReadOnly: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
    });
    
    const emit = defineEmits(["filterChange"]);
    const changed = ref(false);
    const checkedIds = ref<string[]>([]);
    
    const filterValueHasChanged = () => {
      if (props.filter.value === "") {
        clearCheckedIds(props.filter.data as unknown as Node[]);
      }
    };
    
    watch(() => props.filter.value, filterValueHasChanged);
    
    const onUpdate = (nodes: Node[]) => {
      if (piniaRef && props.filter.value === undefined) return;
    
      checkedIds.value = [];
      getCheckedIds(nodes);
    
      //vue 3 doesnt recommend changing v-model values as props, disable warning until fixed
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      props.filter.value =
        checkedIds.value.length > 0 ? checkedIds.value.join(",") : "";
      filterHasChanged();
    
      if (piniaRef && props.filter.immediate) {
        emitFilterChange();
      }
    };
    
    const onNodeClick = (node: Node) => {
      const checked = node.checked;
      if (Array.isArray(node.nodes)) {
        node.nodes.forEach((childNode) => {
          childNode.checked = checked;
        });
      }
    };
    
    const getCheckedIds = (nodes: Node[]) => {
      if (Array.isArray(nodes)) {
        nodes.forEach((node) => {
          if (Array.isArray(node.nodes)) {
            getCheckedIds(node.nodes);
          } else if (node.checked) {
            checkedIds.value.push(node.id);
          }
        });
      }
    };
    
    const clearCheckedIds = (nodes: Node[]) => {
      if (Array.isArray(nodes)) {
        nodes.forEach((node) => {
          node.checked = false;
          if (Array.isArray(node.nodes)) {
            clearCheckedIds(node.nodes);
          }
        });
      }
    };
    
    const filterHasChanged = () => {
      changed.value = true;
    };
    
    const emitFilterChange = () => {
      if (changed.value) {
        emit("filterChange", props.filter);
        changed.value = false;
      }
    };
</script>
```

This error keeps breaking in production causing an infinite rerender, but works fine in development. I have tried putting the props in a ref and in a computed method, but to no avail.

Any helps is greatly appreciated.